# How do I make a variable available in all Jinja2 templates?

Tags: python, templates, jinja2, html-rendering

Is there a way to make a variable available in all templates by default?

I have this variable in app.py

```
STATIC_URL = 'http://myhost.com/x/static'
```

I want to make this variable available by default in all the templates rendered suing Jinja2. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Put it in jinja's Environement's [globals variable](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#jinja2.Environment.globals).